# Hide time in transaction mails with {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated(''short'')}}

Tags: php, magento, email, date, mage

I have a little problem. I only want to display the date without time in my order mails.

For that I have to use  `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated(''short'')}}` afaik. But it is still showing the time. Of course I searched the Magento source and I am wondering why it's not working.

When I look into `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` I can find that:

```
/**
* Get formated order created date in store timezone
*
* @param   string $format date format type (short|medium|long|full)
* @return  string
*/

public function getCreatedAtFormated($format)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, true);
    }
```

Looking further into `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php` shows this:

```
public function formatDate($date = null, $format = Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, $showTime = false)
{
    if (!in_array($format, $this->_allowedFormats, true)) {
        return $date;
    }
    if (!($date instanceof Zend_Date) && $date && !strtotime($date)) {
        return '';
    }
    if (is_null($date)) {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtTimestamp(), null, null);
    } else if (!$date instanceof Zend_Date) {
        $date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(strtotime($date), null, null);
    }

    if ($showTime) {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat($format);
    } else {
        $format = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat($format);
    }

    return $date->toString($format);
}
```

So shouldn't it already hide the time when I pass the short argument to that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mage::helper('core')->formatDate(null, Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, false);`

The last parameter allows for time to be hidden:

```
public function formatDate($date = null, $format = Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT, $showTime = false)
```

That is very annoying of Magento really, to provide a wrapper to a method but not provide full access. Why they haven't written the method like the following I don't know...

```
public function getCreatedAtFormated($format, $showTime = true)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, $showTime);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your nice help. But did I forget something? I changed the function like you suggested but the time is still shown.

Comment: @SimonK. How are you calling it? `{{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('short', false)}}`? Hmmm I am not sure if sending boolean arg works from email template.

Comment: I was calling it only with the short argument before but sadly I have to confirm that it's not working with the boolean as well.

Comment: @SimonK. You are going to have to create a new method to get your time which will basically just call `Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, false);` Fairly annoying to have to rewrite the model to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. With an additional function it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php, create a new function

```
public function getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime($format)
{
    return Mage::helper('core')->formatDate($this->getCreatedAtStoreDate(), $format, false);
}
```

So you can call it from mail template:

```
{{var order.getCreatedAtFormatedHideTime('short')}}
```

Output:

01/01/2000