# Magento: How to get current date in magento email template

Tags: magento, email

How can I get Current date in Magento email template?

`{{var dateAndTime}}` doesn't work. I need to get current date in which the email is sent.

Comment: Please provide some code here. So that I can able to checkout .

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19221799/hide-time-in-transaction-mails-with-var-order-getcreatedatformatedshort) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options.
**Option 1.**  is to rewrite the method that sends the e-mail and pass the current date as a parameter.
Let's say for example that you want to show the date in the order e-mail.
For that you will need to rewrite the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::sendNewOrderEmail` method.
You need to change this:

```
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
        )
    );
```

To this:

```
   $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'order'        => $this,
            'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
            'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
            'dateAndTime'  => Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), //change format as needed.
        )
    );
```

Then you will be able to use `{{var dateAndTime}}` in your new order email template.
This is handy if you want to use your date and time in only one template.
If you want a more general case you need to create your own directive see option 2.

**Option 2** creating your own `{{}}` directive.
Let's say that you want in every e-mail to use {{dateAndTime}} to print to current date and time.
You need to rewrite the class `Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter` and add a new method to it.
[See this detailed explanation about how to do it](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4958/146).
Your new method should look like this:

```
public function dateAndTimeDirective($construction) {
    return Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

You can even take it up a notch and be able to pass the date format as a parameter like this:

```
 {{dateAndTime format="Y-m-d"}}
```

in this case your method that handles the directive should look like this:

```
public function dateAndTimeDirective($construction) {
    $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]); 
    $format = isset($params['format']) ? $params['format'] : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'
    return Mage::getModel('core/date')->date($format);
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Adding method on `Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter` didn't work, I dont know why. but i added the same method on `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter` and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your email template from admin panel. Use block directive as follows

   current date is :

   ```
   {{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='page/html/date.phtml'}}
   ```
2. Now create a new file `date.phtml` in your template as follows

   ```
   app/design/frontend/yourtheme/yourtemplate/page/html/date.phtml
   ```
3. Add following code in php tags (use php date function and echo current date i.e `date('d-m-Y')`)

   ```
   <pre><code>
       $date = date('d-m-Y');
       echo $date;
   </code></pre>
   ```

Hope this helps!